# How to solve the classical mechanics rocket equation using Maple?

Tags: classical-mechanics, maple

I would like to derive the Rocket Equation from Classical Mechanics in Maple.

I will do the case of zero external force:
$$F^{ext}=0=m(t)\frac{dv}{dt}-u \frac{dm}{dt}$$
where u is the velocity of the exhaust relative to the rocket, v is the velocity of the rocket, and m is the mass of the rocket.
$$m(t)\frac{dv}{dt}=u\frac{dm}{dt}$$
$$um(t)^{-1}dm=dv$$
$$\int_{v(t_0)}^{v(t_f)}dv=\int_{m_0}^{m_f}um(t)^{-1}dm$$
$$v(t_f)=v(t_0)+u\ln{\frac{m_f}{m_0}}$$

In Maple

```
RE := 0 = m(t)*diff(v(t), t) - u*diff(m(t), t);
```

**The question is, how do I get Maple to solve this differential equation as it is solved above?**

```
dsolve(RE);
Error, (in dsolve) Required a specification of the indeterminate function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation has both `m(t)` and `v(t)`.

You seem to expect that Maple ought to be able to somehow know that you want a solution for `v(t)` in terms of `m(t)`, instead of the reverse.

The `dsolve` command can be called with a second argument that specifies the indeterminate function, ie the unknown function of `t`. But your call to `dsolve` does not supply that. The error message occurs because of the ambiguity.

```
restart;

RE := 0 = m(t)*diff(v(t), t) - u*diff(m(t), t):

dsolve({RE}, {v(t)});

     {v(t) = u ln(m(t)) + _C1}

raw := dsolve({RE, v(t__0)=v__0}, {v(t)});

    v(t) = u ln(m(t)) + v__0 - u ln(m(t__0))

combine(raw, symbolic);

                / m(t)  \       
     v(t) = u ln|-------| + v__0
                \m(t__0)/
```